# ActiveAdmin filter via activerecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin, ransack

In a rails project I have two models:

```
# id
# email
# password
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :guests, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
# id
# name
class Guest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I need to create a filter in the ActiveAdmin Index page of Guest that enables me to filter Guests by selecting a specific user email. I can easily create a column that displays the user email:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Guest do
  index do
    column :user, sortable: 'users.email'
    column :name
  end

  filter :user, as: :select

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :user, as: :select
      f.input :name
    end
    actions
  end

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      end_of_association_chain.includes(:user)
    end
  end
end
```

If I follow the same approach for the filter and New/Edit form (as in the above code)  instead of displaying the user email the list shows something like this:

```
#<User:0x000000010774eb88>
#<User:0x000000010774ea98>
```

How do I fix this and enable ActiveAdmin to show the email instead of this weird string?

Answer (score -1):

You may use the `collection` option and pass it a collection of users with their emails to show the user email instead of the object in the filter and form.
You may construct a method in your admin file's controller block that returns a collection of users and their emails, and then provide it to the `collection` option when establishing the filter and form fields.

U can try do it this way:

```rb
  ActiveAdmin.register Guest do
  index do
    column :user, sortable: 'users.email'
    column :name
  end

  filter :user, as: :select, collection: -> { User.all.map { |user| [user.email, user.id] } }

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :user, as: :select, collection: -> { User.all.map { |user| [user.email, user.id] } }
      f.input :name
    end
    actions
  end

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      end_of_association_chain.includes(:user)
    end
  end
end
```

U will be able to filter the guests based on the user email and also assign the user email to the visitor when creating or modifying a guest in this manner.